# Scrollbar moves fixed div

Tags: scrollbar, navbar, fixed

I have a fixed navbar that that positions itself correctly if the page have a scrollbar. But some of my pages appears without a scrollbar and then the navbar jumps to the right.

CSS for my navbar:

```
header#masthead {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This makes it work when the scrollbar is visible:

```
body{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Have tried this without sucess, nothing happens:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[My website](https://www.officeofpossibilities.se/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header#masthead {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Was the solution!